# Angular JS, Image Menu

Tags: angularjs

I want to develop an app using images as my menu button, however, i want to blur the other images that was not clicked or change the color of the image that was on clicked. please help me out on this, I'm new in using angularjs
      
            
                
                    
                    System Status

```
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
            <a class="thumbnail setting_subcatalog_icon" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image/subcatalog_system_1_h.png" alt="">
                <p class="subcatalog_name_h">System<br>Settings</p>                       
            </a>             
        </div>

         <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
            <a class="thumbnail setting_subcatalog_icon" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image/subcatalog_system_1_h.png" alt="">
                <p class="subcatalog_name_h">Time and Date<br></p>                       
            </a>             
        </div>

         <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
            <a class="thumbnail setting_subcatalog_icon" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image/subcatalog_system_1_h.png" alt="">
                <p class="subcatalog_name_h">Firmware<br>Update</p>                       
            </a>             
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
            <a class="thumbnail setting_subcatalog_icon" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image/subcatalog_system_1_h.png" alt="">
                <p class="subcatalog_name_h">USB<br>Devices</p>                       
            </a>             
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. Please have a look at this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pinro/pen/OMLRxW)

**Explanation:** In ng-class I am giving a condition if toggleObject.item value is equal to index value of the list, then set a class to image-active. In controller i have initialised toggleObject.item to -1 so if you not click the item condition will not fulfil and image-active class will not apply.

CSS:

```
.image-active{
filter: blur(0px) !important;
   -webkit-filter: blur(0px) !important;
}

.image-deactive{
  filter: blur(20px);
   -webkit-filter: blur(20px);

}
```

HTML:

```
 <img class="image-deactive" ng-class="{'image-active' : toggleObject.item == $index}" ng-src={{client.image}} alt="">
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.toggleObject = {item: -1};
```

Comment: thank you, i would like to ask where should i put the controller part?

Comment: thank you, i would like to ask where part should I put the controller?

Comment: You can either put controller inside HTML in <script> tag above </body> or create a separate .js file and reference that after angularjs load.